# Java - Opening a website

Tags: java, url, action

How do I open a website using a JButton in Java?

Comment: I don't get your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Desktop API#browse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) to achieve it.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            openWebpage("http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask");
        }
    });

public void openWebpage(URI uri) {
  Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```